# How to unmarshal <!DOCTYPE> element in JAXB from a input XML?

Tags: xml, jaxb, dtd, unmarshalling

I am facing an issue while doing the unmarshal using JAXB of an input XML doc. The XML doc looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<!DOCTYPE Power SYSTEM "http://someuri/TestModel_v9.dtd">
<Power>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Control>
        <Inp1>MyInp</Inp1>
        <Inp2>MyInp</Inp2>
    </Control>
</Power>
```

I have already generated JAXB classes and able to access all the unmarshalled data except DOCTYPE. I need the DOCTYPE section also as part of unmarshalled data. I am using Unmarshaller.unmarshal method in JAXB. A snippet of unmarshalling using JAXB.

```
File file = new File("C:\\file.xml");
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Power.class);

Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
Power power= (Power) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
```

Any idea how I can achieve that? If JAXB is not able to do this, please suggest any alternative work around which I can use along with JAXB.

Thanks,
Bhaskar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can capture the doctype information if you use JAXB with StAX.

**XMLResolver (MyXMLResolver)**

Here is an implementation of `XMLResolver` you can use to capture the doctype information.

```java
import javax.xml.stream.XMLResolver;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;

public class MyXMLResolver implements XMLResolver {

    private String publicID;
    private String systemID;
    private String baseURI;
    private String namespace;

    @Override
    public Object resolveEntity(String publicID, String systemID,
            String baseURI, String namespace) throws XMLStreamException {
        this.publicID = publicID;
        this.systemID = systemID;
        this.baseURI = baseURI;
        this.namespace = namespace;
        return null;
    }

    public String getPublicID() {
        return publicID;
    }

    public String getSystemID() {
        return systemID;
    }

    public String getBaseURI() {
        return baseURI;
    }

    public String getNamespace() {
        return namespace;
    }

}
```

**Demo**

Here is how you leverage it in your use case:

```java
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.stream.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        MyXMLResolver resolver = new MyXMLResolver();
        xif.setXMLResolver(resolver);
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new StreamSource("input.xml"));

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Power.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Power power = (Power) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr);

        System.out.println(resolver.getPublicID());
        System.out.println(resolver.getSystemID());
        System.out.println(resolver.getBaseURI());
        System.out.println(resolver.getNamespace());
    }

}
```